Azure backend API doesnt work after writing tests
I'm working on the C# backend (on Azure) for my React weather application. Using this backend, I retrieve user data from the database and make API calls to fetch weather data. The backend itself was functioning as intended, but my task was to write tests for it. So, I added a tests folder to the solution at the same level as the backend service. Within that folder, I wrote tests for individual controllers. Here is an example of testing of UserController:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FluentAssertions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using stin_backend.Controllers;
using stin_backend.Models;
using Xunit;

namespace Tests.Controller
{
    public class UserControllerTest
    {
        private readonly DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> _dbContextOptions;

        public UserControllerTest()
        {
            _dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabaseContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "UsersControllerTests")
                .Options;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task GetUser_ShouldReturnAllUsers()
        {
            // Arrange
            var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabaseContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TestDatabase")
                .Options;

            using (var context = new DatabaseContext(dbContextOptions))
            {
                if (!context.User.Any(u => u.id == 1))
                {
                    context.User.Add(new User { id = 1, username = "John", password = "password", pay = "100" });
                }

                if (!context.User.Any(u => u.id == 2))
                {
                    context.User.Add(new User { id = 2, username = "Jane", password = "password", pay = "200" });
                }

                context.SaveChanges();

                var controller = new UsersController(context);

                // Act
                var result = await controller.GetUser();

                // Assert
                result.Value.Should().BeAssignableTo<IEnumerable<User>>();

                var users = result.Value as IEnumerable<User>;
                users.Should().HaveCount(2);
                users.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(
                    new User { id = 1, username = "John", password = "password", pay = "100" },
                    options => options.ExcludingMissingMembers()
                );
                users.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(
                    new User { id = 2, username = "Jane", password = "password", pay = "200" },
                    options => options.ExcludingMissingMembers()
                );
            }
        }
...

All these tests passed on my computer. The project hierarchy looks like this:

When I try executing GET, POST and other functions on Swagger, it works fine, but after uploading tests to my GitHub folder, which is connected to Azure, every time I try to call GET, POST or any other command from Azure API management service, it returns this error:

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error cache-control: private content-length: 2416 content-type: text/html date: Sun, 19 May 2024 09:15:49 GMT vary: Origin x-powered-by: ASP.NET
HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start
Common solutions to this issue:
The app failed to start
The app started but then stopped
The app started but threw an exception during startup
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
For more guidance on diagnosing and handling these errors, visit
Troubleshoot ASP.NET Core on Azure App Service and IIS.

Any ideas how to fix it, so my API works with tests as well?
When I delete Tests from GitHub, it works fine again, but I need to have them there, so I can get Codecov summary.

I suggest you put your tests in a separate project

Also, do as the error message tells you and look at the app logs on Azure

It's important to ignore those files which are not needed on the build: .gitignore, stin-backend.http and you folder with the tests.
You can use the paths-ignore of github actions to ignore the Tests folder when building. Asumming the folder is in the root of the project, add this to your stin-backend-service.yml.
on:
  push:
    paths-ignore:
      - 'Tests/**'

This only ignore files inside Tests folder.
